# Top-to-Bottom, Left-to-Right stacking of variable-height, fixed-width divs in 2 or more columns

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I want to layout *variable-height* but *fixed-width* divs inside a *fixed-width* and *variable-height* container, so that the child divs look stacked on one another in a masonry kind of pattern, taking 2 or more columns.

Here's what I want:

[image]

And here's what I get with floats or FlexBox:

[image]

Here's the code pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xOLwVJ

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <div class="item" style="height:250px;">
  </div>
  <div class="item" style="height:150px;">
  </div>
  <div class="item" style="height:200px;">
  </div>
  <div class="item" style="height:180px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

This code is only in reference to CodePen, not meant to represent the 2 images here.

Neither Flexbox nor Floats seem to work. The closest I have come to making it work is using columns, however they cut of child divs in the middle - it's ok for text, but not so for actual boxes.

I want HTML/CSS only solution with no JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But I would like a solution with no JS dependency. So maybe columns will do the trick or something else I have not thought of...

Comment: You will need javascript if they are not set heights.

Comment: Did you see this article? [Creating a CSS-only Responsive Masonry](http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it is possible with CSS columns after all. The trick was to set `display:inline-block` on child elements to prevent child divs being cut in the middle on column wraps.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
  </div>
  <div class="item" style="height:250px;">
  </div>
  <div class="item" style="height:150px;">
  </div>
  <div class="item" style="height:200px;">
  </div>
  <div class="item" style="height:180px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:600px;
  background:#ddd;
  display: block;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
}
  .item {
    margin:10px;
    background:red;
    width:270px;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block; /* this is to prevent div being cut in the middle when it flows onto the next column */
  }
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GqvoBO

Answer (score 0):

this is jsfiddle for your question i hope this is useful for you (https://jsfiddle.net/ahe128/anhw21rj/)

```
<div id="main">
<div id="coloumn1">
  <div id="row1_1">
  </div>
   <div id="row1_2">
  </div>
    <div id="row1_3">
  </div>
</div>
<div id=coloumn2>
 <div id="row2_1">
  </div>
   <div id="row2_2">
  </div>
</div>
</div>

#main{
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin:10px;
}
#coloumn1{
  height:400px;
  width:200px;
  float:left;
margin:10px;
   border:2px solid black;
}
#row1_1{
  height:150px;
  width:150px;
   border:1px solid black;
   margin:10px;
}
#row1_2{
  height:100px;
  width:150px;
margin:10px;
 border:1px solid black;
}
#row1_3{
  height:50px;
  width:150px;
margin:10px;
 border:1px solid black;
}
#coloumn2{
  height:400px;
  width:200px;
  float:left;
   border:2px solid black;
   margin:10px;
}
#row2_1{
  height:200px;
  width:150px;
   border:1px solid black;
   margin:10px;
}
#row2_2{
  height:150px;
  width:150px;
margin:10px;
 border:1px solid black;
}
```